# Search every occurence of a substring in a string C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, performance

I know that similar questions and problems were already discussed here, but not exactly the ones I need.

Let's face the problem, that we have a long string, a really long one, the haystack, and we have a needle. Classic problem: search the occurences, all of it. Well `Regex.Matches` is a nice function, it only have one problem, which in our case is a serious problem, it doesn't count overlapped strings.

For example

```
string haystack = "(anything)....bbb....(anything)";  
string needle = "bb"; //must be a string not a char
```

Now we see, that `bb` is 2x in that `bbb` part of the haystack. (`BBb` and `bBB`) `Regex.Matches` only finds the first one, and he searches further from the third `b`. And will not find any other.

Any idea how to search fur substrings with overlapping option in a long haystack string (must be efficient of course)?

Thank you, and sorry if duplicate.

Comment: use string.IndexOf(string, fromPosition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string.IndexOf in a loop

```
string haystack = "(anything)....bbb....(anything)";  
string needle = "bb"; 
int pos = 0;
while((pos = haystack.IndexOf(needle, pos)) != -1)
{
    Console.Write("Found at pos:" + pos.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(" - " + haystack.Substring(pos, needle.Length));
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Steve thank you for your idea, seems to work nicely, I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way, but it's better than my solution :)

Comment: Well, at least is simpler. I have tested the solution from Matt, it is faster in matching but it seems to be slower when you try to print out the found strings and probably your test string is just an example (I don't think you really search for bb). However I think that this is just a micro-optimization and unless you have evidence of a performance problem, I would not worry too much for efficiency here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just maintain a pointer of where the substring is found then resume your Regex.Matches from that position + 1 whenever a match is found.

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution is to use `string.IndexOf` in a loop as others have suggested, but...if you really want to use Regex, you can use a positive lookahead to deal with overlaps. For example:

```
string test = "(anything)....bbb....(anything)";
Regex r = new Regex("b(?=b)");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(test)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("match at: {0}",m.Index));
}
```

Will match at both indexes `14` and `15`.

This is manageable for a 2 character match, but might become a pain with longer matches.

Determining whether or not this would be faster *in practice* than the `string.IndexOf` in a loop solution is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit**: Because curiosity got the better of me, I had to try and figure out which one is actually faster, here's some test code:

http://dotnetfiddle.net/qneK5u

```
        string test = "(anything)....bbbbbb....(anything)";
        Regex r = new Regex("b(?=b)");
        var s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        int i=0; 
        int l=5000;
        for (;i<l;i++) {
            var result = r.Matches(test);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
        i = 0;
        string needle = "bb"; 
        int pos = 0;
        s.Reset();
        s.Start();
        for (;i<l;i++) {
            pos = 0;
            while((pos = test.IndexOf(needle, pos)) != -1)
            {
                pos++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedTicks.ToString());
```

The regex solution come out significantly faster, but I'm not sure if I'm doing a fair test.

Comment: I was also curious because I have always thought that RegEx is slower than any string functions, but you are right. Regex is faster in matching the values. However this is just the first half of the problem. Now that you have a Match collection, what happen if you try to print out (use) the values in the collection. In my test this transform again the Regex in the slower one.

Comment: Hi @Matt, you're right this (precisely this) solution is about 30x faster as the IndexOf, BUT considering  that my needle is a variable (in both length and content), for my issue this is not working properly. But thank you anyways!

Comment: @Steve: I suspected as much if for no other reason than the `Match` object is go much more heavy-weight than the `int` being used in the second case. If all you need is the index, then the loop is probably a better bet (and I tend to think using regex here is a little overkill anyway). This [test](http://dotnetfiddle.net/6YIlwr) seems to show that there is, indeed, a reversal if you actually loop through the `MatchCollection`

Comment: @solotherm: I'm pretty sure you could adapt this to work with variable "needles". You basically just need a look ahead for everything that isn't the first character of your match. It's still probably overkill either way.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the list of indexes of the starting matching needle string (may be faster than regex):

```
    public static List<int>  GetPositions(string haystack , string needle)
    {
        List<int> ret = new List<int>();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(haystack) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(needle))
            return ret;
        for(int i=0;i<haystack.Length-needle.Length+1;i++)
        {
            int j = 0;
            for(;j<needle.Length && haystack[i+j]==needle[j];j++);
            if(j==needle.Length )
                ret.Add(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
```